# Webpack/Web Worker - Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, web-worker

For initial context, I have a web worker `worker.ts` that imports a function from `module_a.ts`.

`file_a.ts` imports a function from `file_b.ts`, to see what string to return. For simplification purposes, I turned the function to

```
function returnString(path: string): string {
    return 'this is a string'
}
```

, calling it with `returnString(path)`. On Webpack, I have the configuration

```
entry: {
    app: pathName,
    worker: './path/worker'
},
output: {
    path: anotherPathName,
    filename: '[name].js'
}
```

pertaining to the worker. And with just that, everything works as intended. However, the function inside `file_b.ts`, that returns a string, should be in yet another file. By having a `file_c.ts` with all of its contents being

```
function returnString(path: string): string {
    return 'this is a string'
}

export default {
    returnString,
}
```

and importing it in `file_b.ts` with `import { retStr } from '@project-name/services'`, then calling it with `retStr.returnString(path)`, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

It's worth noting that while the actual function in place of `returnString` is more complex, I've tried the code with `returnString` itself and it still works in the first case, while failing in the second. I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340806/uncaught-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-p5-js-web-worker). I believe the cause of the problem has to do with Webpack generating `document` inside `worker.js`, but I don't know the solution nor why putting the content of `file_b.ts` inside `file_c.ts` is causing the problem.